# Accessing a URL Param Project.find(params[:project_id]) in the application_helper.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to build a helper called

```
def current_project
    @current_project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
end
```

I want this so that in the navigation plugin I'm using I can use current_project to populate the navigation.

Problem I'm having is while params[:project_id] is available in the navigation config (navigation.rb) it is not working in the application_helper.rb. I get the following error:

"find_with_ids': Couldn't find Project without an ID"

Here's the navigation plugin, in case you're curious: http://github.com/andi/simple-navigation/

ideas why?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If passing in the project_id to the helper it not an option, you can put the method into the controller and mark it as a `helper_method`. For example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_project

  private
    def current_project
      @current_project ||= Project.find(params[:project_id])
    end
end
```

Then in your views you can call it with:

```
<% current_project %>
```

as you expect.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
def current_project
    @current_project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
end
```

Try

```
def current_project( project_id )
        @current_project = Project.find( project_id )
end
```

When invoking the helper, pass the params[:project_id] for project_id param value.

Comment: +1 for Jas, passing params values to a helper method argument will also make testing helpers infinitely easier.

Comment: But the problem is I'm using a simple-navigation plugin that has a navigation.rb config file which doesn't have access to params[:project_id] Which is why I need the helper to grab it. If I could get the project_id in the navigation.rb config file I wouldn't need the helper. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you store it inside session by the controller handling request which is receiving the params value , e.g. session[:project_id] = params[:project_id] ?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely agree with rjk, you should put it in application controller, because if you don't your controllers can't access the method. The issue you're getting seems to be due to a nil id (e.g. params[:project_id] isn't passed through in every request) presumably it's only passed in the navigation action which switches between projects?

I'm not sure what the internals of simple navigation do, but if `params[:project_id]` is only passed in the navigation action, then the navigation action should be storing this in the session `session[:project_id] = params[:project_id].to_i`, then you would define a private controller method + helper as follows, using the session stored id so you can access it in other actions:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_project

  private
    def current_project
      @current_project ||= Project.find(session[:project_id])
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, that's awesome info! Do you happen to know anything about nested resources? I've been pounding my head against the wall all day on this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910345/form-for-a-nested-resources-permissions-y-model) thanks!